# Какое решение выбрать для создания мобильного приложения под кафе/ресторан?

Tags: mobile-web

Добрый день.
Вопрос мой адресован людям, у которых есть опыт в создании мобильных приложений.
Поясню: я работаю в ресторане в качестве управляющего и у меня возникла идея увеличить поток

посетителей через мобильное приложение, в котором будет указано меню ресторана + инструменты

лояльности, которые в дальнейшем дадут небольшую скидку, если человек вернётся в ресторан

повторно.
Основная проблема в том, что я не шарю в создании мобильных приложений и как выход из ситуации

нашел пока несколько сайтов, которые позволяют создавать мобильные приложения по шаблону:

[app-global.ru](http://app-global.ru) - русскоязычная платформа

Иностранные платформы:

- [appery.io](http://appery.io)
- [mobileroadie.com](http://mobileroadie.com)
- [theappbuilder.com](http://theappbuilder.com)
- [goodbarber.com](http://goodbarber.com)
- [appypie.com](http://appypie.com)
- [appmachine.com](http://appmachine.com)
- [biznessapps.com](http://biznessapps.com)
- [appmakr.com](http://appmakr.com)
- [shoutem.com](http://shoutem.com)

Сейчас 2 основных вопроса:

1. пользовался ли кто-либо данными шаблонами? если "да", то каково ваше впечатление?
2. есть ли у кого-то практический опыт в создании приложений для кафе/ресторанов? на какой платформе вы создавали данное приложение и насколько успешен был ваш опыт?

Comment: Добрый день. Вопрос мой адресован людям, у которых есть опыт работы шеф-поваром. Поясню: я работаю программистом и у меня возникла идея основать ресторан. Основная проблема в том, что я не умею готовить и как выход из ситуации нашел несколько сайтов с рецептами. Есть иностранные книги про диеты всякие. Ну, они просто есть где-то. На складах Амазона, например. Поэтому осталось только два вопроса: пользовался ли кто-нибудь кулинарными рецептами и если да, то каково ваше впечатление? Есть ли у кого-то практический опыт ухода из программистов в шеф-повара и владельцы ресторанов? Насколько успешно

Comment: @VadimTukaev, 80 lvl тролл ))

Comment: @zorba89 если не "шарите", оставьте это тем, кто "шарит". Дайте им денег (как ни прискорбно, но бесплатно никто это делать не станет, а если вдруг и станет, то результат будет таков, что посетителей вы только потеряете), и все технические вопросу оставьте решать им - вам этим заниматься явно не стоит. 
Более того, я, например, не слышал о " сайтах, которые позволяют создавать мобильные приложения по шаблону". Совершенно не удивлюсь, если такие существуют, однако же на 146% уверен, что результат от них будет на уровне поделки школьника из фольги и желудей с уроков труда

Comment: @DreamChild есть такие сайты. Но на выходе приложение - визитка получается. Статичные данные и оформление. 
@zorba89 На этих сайтах вы не сможете сделать приложение с гибкой логикой, а так как вам нужно делать скидки, учёт клиентов и тд, вам не обойтись без серверов с базами данных. Посмотрите на аналоги у конкурентов(Сеть вай-мэ например) и решите что вы хотите видеть, затем обратитесь к специалистам.

Comment: @Deadkenny я не удивлен, что подобные сайты существуют, однако ждать от них  чудес удобства, красоты и функциональности явно не приходится. Я, как гипотетический пользователь ресторанного приложения, вряд ли стал бы пользоваться услугами того ресторана, который предлагает свои услуги с помощью состряпанного на коленке приложения-визитки. Поэтому на мой взгляд лучше уж немного потратить на услуги нормального разработчика (тем более что для ресторана это вряд ли станет неподъемной суммой) и потом пользоваться качественным прилежением, чем экономить на спичках и получить своеобразную антирекламу

Comment: @DreamChild не зря есть выражение "Скупой платит дважды". Потеряешь клиентов, придется тратить деньги на рекламу:) А вообще может быть автор под рестораном подразумевает прилавок с чебуреками и ему приложение никак не поможет, все специфично:)

Comment: @DreamChild, есть такие сайты. И "программисты-анроидчики" есть, которые "разрабатывают" на таких инструментах)). К нам недавно пришел такой програмист, я спрашиваю на чем делаете, на java? А он мне смотрить удивленно (я же не знал, что он впервые слышить это слово), и говорить " нет. у нас свои разработки, инструменты". Вот такие у них и инструменты, выяснилось потом...Я в шоке. )

Answer (score 2):

Проблема здесь вот в чем:

1. Приложение которое вы хотите написать по своей природе клиент-серверное, то есть где-то есть сервер, на котором централизованно хранится ваше меню, имена посетителей, скидки и проч. муть.
2. Далее, у посетителей есть мобильное приложение, которое и является клиентом и которое связывается с сервером получая необходимые данные и в свою очередь сервер может оповещать клиента об акциях и проч. (push notification)

Все предлагаемые решения предполагают, что сервер находится у них (у создателей платформы). В принципе в этом нет ничего плохого, хотя и хорошего тоже мало - я бы лично поостерегся хранить данные своего бизнеса на чужом серваке.

Нанимать на стороне фрилансеров под собственную разработку такой клиент-серверной связки достаточно рискованное занятие, скорее всего вам в итоге всучат какие-нибудь костыли в связке: MySQL+PHP - Android через HTTP/JSon без поддержки push и оффлайновых штучек.

Я вижу 2 варианта решения:

1. Либо надо нанимать нормального постановщика задачи, который хотя бы понимает разницу между Java и JavaScript и знает чем отличается форк от бранча, который возьмет на себя труд выбора верного фреймворка, серверной платформы, координацию разработки разношерстной командой фрилансеров и проч. Самим становиться таким человеком не советую - вам лучше продолжать варить борщ.
2. Либо же идти на поклон к означенным платформам, заранее прописывая в контракте возможность переноса серверной части под ваш контроль (ну скажем когда количество установок превысит хотя бы 10 тыс.)